# Having issue with installing this in my mac terminal

Tags: ios

I cannnot figure out why it's giving me this result.

```
Warning: Failed to create the file /Users/myname/.bash_profile: Permission 

Warning: denied

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1968)
```

When I enter the second step see in the link below.

[image]

Instructions provided here that I was given from a bootcamp I am learning to code from.
If some one could take the time out their day to please answer my question. I would gladly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with "sudo" in front of the command?

Comment: You should post actual commands and the error message as text, not as images.

Comment: Okay, I'm curious as to why though?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try appending "sudo" in the beginning of the command.

If that does not work, attempt to edit permissions for the directory by using chmod.

Be careful with using `777`, but if it is on your local device, it should not mean a whole lot.

Usage: `sudo chmod XYZ /di/rec/tory`

Replace `XYZ` with chmod settings.

Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) if you are in doubt.